how to setup cron jobs in ionos for each minute to run
I have a laravel app hosted on ionos web server.
I have set the route for the schedule to run
Route::get('/run-currency-update', function () {
    Log::info('Currency update command triggered');
    Artisan::call('CurrencyUpdate:auto');
    return response()->json(['status' => 'Currency update command triggered']);
});

In the cron job manager, there's only daily and hour selection. I want this route to be in get request each minute.
How can I do that with ionos?
I created it to run 4 times daily. But I need it to run every minute.

I'm not being silly, but try a different webhost.  One that provides you with SSH access and cron jobs

If the IONOS cron job manager only allows for daily and hourly selections and doesn't provide an option for every minute, you can still achieve your goal using the following methods:
Method 1: Use an External Cron Job Service
You can use a third-party service to trigger your Laravel route every minute. Here are a few options:

EasyCron
Cron-job.org

Method 2: Check with IONOS Support
Sometimes web hosting providers can help you with cron job limitations. Consider reaching out to IONOS support to see if they can enable a more granular cron job scheduling option for you.
Method 3: Alternative Approach (Using a Queue)
If you're open to alternative methods, consider implementing a job that runs every minute through Laravel's task scheduling
You would need to set up a cron job on your server to run Laravel's scheduler every minute. If that's not possible with IONOS directly, you might still have to use one of the external services mentioned above.
